# Is there an open source C# based RDP implementation out there?

Tags: c#, rdp

Is anyone aware of an open source C# based implementation of RDP?  Specifically something similar to ProperJavaRDP or Rdesktop.

I'm not looking for addins, 3party controles, etc.  I'm looking for a native C# implementation with source.

Comment: You could try to figure out what http://terminals.codeplex.com uses

Comment: Nearly all 3rd party RDP clients on windows use the RDP activex component, because it provides a full and complete implementation of RDP.  As such, why would anyone want to create a C# version since most people (not all) use C# on windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is to port the rdesktop code. It's already ported it to java so that should give you a good starting point.

http://properjavardp.sourceforge.net/

Comment: This really does seem to be the closest open source rdp solution out there.  It's the only one that isn't using some closed source or microsoft provided trickery.

Answer (score 1):

Just letting you know: I'm working on writing C# bindings to FreeRDP as part of a sister project called Screenary: https://github.com/Screenary/Screenary

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at 
[This CodeProject How to Write a Terminal Services Add-in in Pure C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/TSAddinInCS.aspx) by Selvin

**Update:**
Or look at gnome-rdp at sourceforge.net. (close - but "no cigar" - since this is a C# (Mono) wrapper for rdesktop etc.) 
The hard way is to port an existing RDP client, from C/C++ to C# - ex. CoRD (found on sourceforge.net)

/Erling Damsgaard
DNS-IT ApS

Comment: Unfortunately, all that article does is use the RDP api, it doesn't create it's own (presumably portable) RDP interpreter and display client.

Answer (score 0):

or use terminals (terminals.codeplex.com)